# angular и библиотека ngx indexed db

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, indexeddb

Пытаюсь с помощью курсора обойти все записи в таблице из indexeddb. Хочу вытаскивать данные из таблицы порциями, а не все сразу, но никак не получается.

```js
loadNotes() {
    this.dbService.openCursor('notes').subscribe((evt: any) => {
      var cursor: any = (evt.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result;
      if (cursor) {
        console.log(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
      } else {
        console.log('Entries all displayed.');
      }
    });
  }
```

В документации к библиотеке ngx-indexed-db есть пример использования, я переписал почти один в один, только добавил :any для cursor, иначе проект не собирался.
Но пример не работает, функция выводит console.log(cursor.value) только один раз. В таблице записей больше. Да и в блок else никогда не заходит. В чем дело?